# How can i give a setup such that u can slide between two layouts

Tags: android-viewpager

I've tried implementing ViewPager as given in http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

But this doesn't work for buttons. You can add button in layout but couldnt add the onClickListener. It throws Exception while calling this statement:
button.setOnClickListener();

Answer (score 0):

Tabs with a swipe views could be what your looking for: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Your question is very broad, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.